# How can I clean up multi-line Bunyan log output that is coming over an ssh connection?

Tags: docker, ssh, bunyan

`ssh -t -i ~/work/keys/somekey.pem ec2-user@x.x.x.x 'docker logs --follow --tail 50 -t taggoeshere' |  cut -c 32- |  bunyan -o short`

This works well for single line docker log output:

`12:54:49.038  INFO xxxxxxxxxxx: Failed message, sending to S3 (event_id=no-event-id)`

But as soon as it is multiline, it gets ugly. Anyone got a handy trick for cleaning this up?

[image: Output]

Comment: What's ugly about it? For a particular JSON multiline input, what do you want bunyan to output?

Comment: I think if you compare that output to normal bunyan output you'll see the problem pretty quickly. Hint: indents.